# Make Matrix Values below the left-right diagonal are set to 0

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

I have to use this program in order to make this method returns a two-dimensional matrix where:

- The values on and above the left-right diagonal are identical to the values stored in matrixA.
- The values below the left-right diagonal are set to 0 and Assume the number of rows of matrixA equals the number of columns of matrixA.

I have to use this header: `public static int[][] replaceLowerWithZero(int[][] matrixA)`

Here is a clue that i got: Define a two-dimensional array that has the same number of rows
and columns as matrixA. Every element in this array is initially set to zero. Use
a nested loop to change the values on and above the left-right diagonal.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static int[][] getTranspose(int[][] matrixA) {
    int numRows = matrixA.length;
    int numCols = matrixA[0].length;
    int[][] transpose = new int[numCols][numRows];
    for (numRows = 0; numRows < matrixA.length; numRows++) {
        for (numCols = 0; numCols < matrixA[numRows].length; numCols++) {
            tranpose[numCols][numRows]=0;
        }
    }
    return transpose;
}

public static int getLRDiagonalSum(int[][] B) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int rows = 0; rows < B.length; rows++) {
        sum = sum + B[rows][rows];
    }
    return sum;
}
public static int getRLDiagonalSum(int[][] B) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int cols = 0; cols < B.length; cols++) {
        sum = sum + B[cols][cols];
    }
    return sum;
public static int[][] replaceLowerWithZero(int[][] matrixA){
```

Comment: Is the first index supposed to be the row or column index?

Comment: 1) this method returns a two-dimensional matrix that represents the transpose of matrixA.
2)this methods returns the sum of the values stores in the diagonal that starts in the upper-left corner of the matrix and ends in the lower-right corner of the matrix
3)this methods returns the sum of the values stores in the diagonal that starts in the upper-right corner of the matrix and ends in the lower-left corner of the matrix.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. All those methods will work correctly regardless of whether the matrix is stored in row-major or column-major sequence. Setting the lower triangular part of the matrix requires knowing which storage scheme is in use.

Comment: What do you mean by storage scheme?

Comment: Let me put it this way: `matrixA[0]` is an array of `int` values; is it the first row or the first column of `matrixA`?

Comment: I think it is the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach will be very similar to your `getTranspose` method. However, the indexing will be slightly different. Per your comments, let's assume that the matrix is stored column by column (i.e., `matrixA[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> column). If it turns out that this is backwards (and it would seem to be judging from the variable names in your method `getTranspose`), then you will have to revise the logic, but it should be easy to work out how to do it.

Since this is an assignment, I don't want to just dump code into an answer; instead I'll outline how I would approach the problem by providing some of the code along with comments.

First we'll start with the method signature per the assignment:

```
public static int[][] replaceLowerWithZero(int[][] matrixA) {
```

Next, we retrieve the matrix size. Since according to the assignment we can assume a square matrix, all we need is one dimension. Let's call it `n`:

```
    int n = matrixA.length;
```

Now we allocate a new matrix that will be the return value:

```
    int[][] result = new int[n][n];
```

According to the Java language, all the elements of `result` will be initialized to zero. Since that's what you want for the lower triangular part of the result, we only need to copy values from `matrixA` into `result` for elements on and above the diagonal. We can work each column at a time:

```
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < n; colIndex++) {
        int[] column = result[colIndex]; // all elements zero at this point
```

The key to the rest of the logic is to visualize the relationship of the `column` array to the entire matrix: it is a slice down one column. Thus, the elements of `column` that are strictly below the diagonal of `result` are the elements that are at indexes above `colIndex`. That is, element `column[0]` is at column `colIndex` and row 0 and element `column[colIndex]` is on the diagonal at position (`colIndex`, `colIndex`). Only elements at and above the diagonal should be set to non-zero values. This can easily be done with another loop:

```
        for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= colIndex; rowIndex++) {
            // copy the element at position (colIndex, rowIndex) from
            // matrixA to column[rowIndex]
```

I'll leave it to you to translate that bit of pseudocode into actual code and also to finish the method (including returning the result).

If you like (and the assignment rubric permits), you can replace that inner loop with a call to the built-in `static` method [`System.arraycopy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)), which can copy all or part of an array to another array (or to another part of the same array). Working out the correct arguments for the call in this particular case is left as an exercise for the reader. :)